# Using Wongi Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rules, rule-engine

Here's my scenario

I have an incoming `transaction` where it checks for all the `rules` and performs `actions` accordingly.

For example,

A `transaction` of `fund_transfer` with amount `greater 10k` needs `2 checkers` and how do I do it?

Now for a given transaction, I need to find all the rules that match up and perform actions accordingly.

Can you provide any hints for me? Thanks!